# Is there any way to change the separate <td> lines font color using the 'color' tag from the xml

Tags: html, jquery, xml, html-table, fonts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Read XML Data Using jQuery Ajax and Load it in HTML table</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click button to Read XML and Show it in HTML</p>
        <input type="button" value="Read XML" id="btn" />
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hovered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Colour</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Change</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is basic html that I am using to display xml.

I am trying to use this script below to change the color of the text inside  elements dynamically using the 'color' values that I have in an xml file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#tableBody').empty();    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:1313/domestic_equities.xml',           // The file path.
                dataType: 'xml',    
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('stock').each(function() {
                        
                        colorChange = $(this).find('color').text();
                        console.log(colorChange);
    
                        $('#tableBody').append(
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + $(this).find('color').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' + $(this).find('name').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' + $(this).find('code').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' + $(this).find('price').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' + $(this).find('change').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '</tr>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have created a 'colorChange' var but it only seems to be displaying red.

Any help would be great!!

Also this is the xml file where I am getting all the info from, including color

```
<stock-data>
    <stock>
        <name>The a2 Milk Company</name>
        <code>(A2M)</code>
        <price>$7.11</price>
        <change>(+0.02)</change>
        <color>green</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Australian Agricult</name>
        <code>(AAC)</code>
        <price>$1.285</price>
        <change>(+0.005)</change>
        <color>green</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Ardent Leisure Group Ordinary/Units FP Stapled Securities</name>
        <code>(AAD)</code>
        <price>$1.76</price>
        <change>(+0.005)</change>
        <color>green</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Adelaide Brighton</name>
        <code>(ABC)</code>
        <price>$6.555</price>
        <change>(-0.055)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Abacus Property Group Units/ Stapled Securities</name>
        <code>(ABP)</code>
        <price>$4.165</price>
        <change>(-0.005)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Aconex Ltd</name>
        <code>(ACX)</code>
        <price>$5.21</price>
        <change>(-0.07)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>AGL Energy Ltd</name>
        <code>(AGL)</code>
        <price>$25.32</price>
        <change>(-0.44)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Automotive Holdings</name>
        <code>(AHG)</code>
        <price>$3.72</price>
        <change>(-0.01)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Asaleo Care Ltd</name>
        <code>(AHY)</code>
        <price>$1.455</price>
        <change>(-0.135)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Aristocrat Leisure</name>
        <code>(ALL)</code>
        <price>$23.10</price>
        <change>(+0.27)</change>
        <color>green</color>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <name>Als Ltd</name>
        <code>(ALQ)</code>
        <price>$6.85</price>
        <change>(-0.07)</change>
        <color>red</color>
    </stock>
</stock-data>
```

Comment: Does the value red come from somewhere in the xml file?  Try adding this line in there and see what it tells you.  console.log($(this));

Comment: I have added the xml file that I am using to get the color tag from

Answer (score 0):

I can not see anything wrong. Let's try to debug and find out the problem. I also tried with a simple example and it's working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xml = "<stock-data>" +
    "<stock>" +
    "    <name>The a2 Milk Company</name>" +
    "    <code>(A2M)</code>" +
    "    <price>$7.11</price>" +
    "    <change>(+0.02)</change>" +
    "   <color>green</color>" +
    "</stock>" +
    "<stock>" +
    "    <name>Adelaide Brighton</name>" +
    "    <code>(ABC)</code>" +
    "    <price>$6.555</price>" +
    "   <change>(-0.055)</change>" +
    "    <color>red</color>" +
    "</stock>" +
    "</stock-data>" +

  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $(xml).find('stock').each(function() {
        var colorChange = $(this).find('color').text();
        console.log(colorChange);
        
        $('#tableBody').append(
        '<tr>' +
          '<td style="color:' + colorChange + '">' + colorChange +'</td>'+
          '<td>' + $(this).find('name').text() + '</td> ' +
          '<td>' + $(this).find('code').text() + '</td> ' +
          '<td>' + $(this).find('price').text() + '</td> ' +
          '<td>' + $(this).find('change').text() + '</td> ' +
          '</tr>'
        );
    });
  });
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hovered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colour</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Change</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
  </table>

<button id="btn1">Append data</button>

</body>
</html>
```

==> Result:

```
Colour  Name                Code    Price   Change
green   The a2 Milk Company (A2M)   $7.11   (+0.02)
red     Adelaide Brighton   (ABC)   $6.555  (-0.055)
```

Comment: What I'd like to do is change the font color depending on what the xml color tag is. So if the price goes up the front is green, and if the price goes down the font is red.

Comment: You can add the style attribute as my edited code above or add CSS class based on your conditions.